# MVC slow if site has been idle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have several MVC4 sites on my VPS. They all have the same issue. They are so slow (up to 10 seconds to load, which is not a good first impression).

I am aware that when you first load your site, it will take a little while due to various things I've read upon. I understand this.

The problem is the following situation is true.

Publish MVC4 site to server.
Load MVC4 site in browser a PC. Site takes a while to load but expected.
Look at other pages on the site. A few are slow, but generally all is OK.
Close the website.
Reopen the website.
All pages respond well.
Close the website.
Leave it idle for 1 hour.
Open website, it is slow again, as if it's only been published

I can only assume it's something to do with the session, IIS or the app pool

In webforms I used to have tracing, I don't appear to have that in MVC and I don't know how I can debug such an issue.

Comment: That's actually the expected behavior, given that after a period of inactivity the application pool will recycle, to free up unused resources. Check the application pool Recycle settings to configure that duration.

Comment: @PabloRomeo, are you saying that, if a website doesn't get hit every n seconds, that this will happen. When I say slow, I mean up to 10 seconds to load. I use MVC for a few sites, but the traffic is very low, a hundred visits a month. Naturally I'm getting complaints about speed issues, I don't think I can turn back and say it's expected :(

Comment: Correct, however, you can configure that time window. Also, you could try using the AutoStart feature, which would "warmp up" the application after deployment, and after a recycle. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Comment: @PabloRomeo, that seems, IMO, good enough to be an answer, if you're OK to move it as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually the expected behavior, given that after a period of inactivity the application pool will recycle, to free up unused resources. Check the application pool's [Recycle settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to configure that duration.

If you also want additional control on what happens during recycling there are a few options:

- IIS7.5 (ASP.NET 4) supports a feature called ["AutoStart"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series), which can warm up your site after deployment and after recycling.
- IIS8 has additional support through the [Application Initialization](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) Module.

Comment: It's a place for me to start learning how to deal with this slow-on-first-load issue. I find it a shame that Microsoft didn't put more focus on resolving this issue after this many versions of IIS.